# Receiving Dynamic Links In Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using the Firebase Dynamic Links SDK in a Unity project and am receiving dynamic link data in my app in a single scene. But, if you navigate to another scene, the subscription to DynamicLinkReceived does not seem to work.

Both scenes are using the same controller and script and subscribing with

```
DynamicLinks.DynamicLinkReceived += OnDynamicLink;
```

The method OnDynamicLink is called in Scene 1 when I click a test link but not in Scene 2.

Comment: Hi sean, can you please guide me with the basic steps to integrate as I have tried every single thing in the documentation to make dynamic link work. I am integrating firebase dynamic links in my Unity iOS game and my dynamic link only opening App store even though my app is installed. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey there, are you setup to receive dynamic links in your first scene of your game?